# Is it possible to have a null value at a given point of the derivative of function while having this point not a local maximum or minimum?

Tags: derivatives

Is it possible to have a null value at a given point of the *derivative* of a function while having this point not a local maximum or minimum ?

Comment: If by "null" you mean zero, consider $f(x)=x^3$

Comment: @Joe : thank you. This is very interesting. But *how* is it possible ? I thought that *monotonic* function could not have a null derivative ? On wikipedia, it is said that : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function#Monotonicity_in_calculus_and_analysis : "A function f ( x ) is said to be absolutely monotonic over an interval if the derivatives of all orders of f are nonnegative or all nonpositive at all points on the interval"

Comment: Non negative or non positive means $\ge 0$ or $\le 0$, not $>0$ or $<0$. A function has a local extremum at a point if & only if its derivative changes sign at that point.

Comment: Mathieu-- Keep in mind that for example "nonnegative" just means not negative so in particular $0$ is nonnegative.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanations. If I may ask further. I thought that if the function derivate cancels out, it means that we are at maximum or a minimum, but in the example of $y=x^3$, the derivates is null at $x=0$ while it is not an maximum nor a minimum. Is there an *additional* condition in order to have a maximum or a minimum ?

Comment: So what to look for, in order to check if a given x value is a maximum or a minimum : should we we look at (derivate null *and* change of sign of derivative), or should we look at (derivate null *and* sign of the second derivative) ?

Comment: Actually, I believe the definition of a local maximum at $x_0$ is that there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $x$ with $|x-x_0|<\epsilon$, $f(x_0)\ge f(x)$. But a constant function satisfies that at every point, without the derivative changing sign, since it is identically zero. But if a function is continuously differentiable on an open interval containing the point, and the derivative changes sign at the point, then it is a local extremum. If the function is twice differentiable at the point, then the second derivative test may yield sufficient conditions.